# Determine how many entries exist for a certain date

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

All,
I have the following code:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar_events where event_status='booked' and event_type='wedding' GROUP BY start"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
    $row_array['start'] = $row['start'];
    $row_array['end'] = $row['end'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

I'm using the fullcalendar and trying to determine how many events have the same start date. So for example if I had the following dates:

02/06/2012
02/06/2012
03/01/2012
04/05/2012

On dates that have entries in my database I'd like to basically see how many events are on that date and basically say how many spots are left. So for any given date I can have two scheduled events so for 02/06/2012 I'd like it to return "Booked" and for 03/01/2012 I'd like "1 spot left" and etc.

How can I go about doing something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
start, count(*) as used, 2-count(*) as free
FROM calendar_events 
WHERE event_status='booked' 
  and event_type='wedding'
GROUP BY start
```

or as by your comment:

```
SELECT 
date(start) as eventdate, count(*) as used, 2-count(*) as free
FROM calendar_events 
WHERE event_status='booked' 
  and event_type='wedding'
GROUP BY date(start)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works good, however I have just one issue. My data is stored as DATETIME so the entry also has a timestamp which is causing it to not think that there are two on the same day. Any idea how to account for that?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you want to use `COUNT(*)` to return the number of entries in the group. (Remember to give the column an alias so that you can retrieve it.) You should also limit yourself the retrieving only the `start` column since retrieving columns that aren't in the GROUP BY clause is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost done, as the others beat me to the punch.  You can try something like this.  The important part is simply having the count as mentioned.

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,start,end,count(*) as filled FROM calendar_events where event_status='booked' and event_type='wedding' GROUP BY start"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
    $row_array['start'] = $row['start'];
    $row_array['end'] = $row['end'];
    $row_array['filled'] = $row['filled'];
    $row_array['booked'] = ($row['filled'] >= 2) ? true : false;

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```